# ManagedObjectContext Syntax

Tags: swift, swift2, ios9, xcode7

So, it tells me:

> `init()` was deprecated in IOS 9.0: Use -`initWithConcurrencyType`:
>   instead

```
var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
```

That's my code. It gave the error too, so how should I change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since iOS 9 `NSManagedObjectContext()` is deprecated and is recommended to create an `NSManagedObjectContext` with, as hinted, `-initWithConcurrencyType:` instead.

Usage when creating a `NSManagedObjectContext` in iOS 9:

```
let managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
```

With `-initWithConcurrencyType:`, we need to specify a concurrency type.

The above example creates one with a `.MainQueueConcurrencyType`, which is one of the three one can specify:

```
case ConfinementConcurrencyType
```

> Specifies that the context will use the thread confinement pattern.

```
case PrivateQueueConcurrencyType
```

> Specifies that the context will be associated with a private dispatch queue.

```
case MainQueueConcurrencyType
```

> Specifies that the context will be associated with the main queue.

With the deprecated `NSManagedObjectContext()`, if my memory serves, the default was of type `.ConfinementConcurrencyQueue`.

To stay on the topic, if you are dealing with UI elements (i.e., updating a `textLabel` thereby), use the `.MainQueueConcurrencyQueue`.